# How can I check if jcombobox selection has not been selected?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

```
comboGender.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Male", "Female" }));
comboCivilStatus.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Single", "Married", "Widow / Widower", "Divorced" }));


if(txtAddress.getText().trim().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID ADDRESS");
}else if(comboGender.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SELECT A GENDER");
}else if(comboCivilStatus.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SELECT A CIVIL STATUS");
}
```

***just a portion of my code ***

hello stackoverflow. i am new here. and i am also a novice in java programming. i seem to be having a problem that i cannot figured out how solve.

i am trying to make if and else if statements to check whether my textfields and comboboxes are empty. and then trying to return a showMessageDialog telling me to input something. i already figured out how to do the textboxes. but the combobox i cannot seem to understand how to do the syntax. can anyone please help? thank you.

by the way i am using java netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JComboBox#getSelectedIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex()), which will return `-1` if nothing is selected or [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()) which will return `null` if nothing is selected.

```
//...
}else if(comboGender.getSelectedIndex() == -1){
//...
```

Take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Comment: im sorry, can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: How much more do you want?  You have references to the JavaDocs and example code snippet